# Wait for Task to cancel waits forever

Tags: c#, task, cancellation

I have a Form in which I start a Task to load the content. If the User clicks Cancel this Task needs to be cancelled of course. But it seems I'm doing something wrong. The form never closes and keeps waiting for the task:

```
public partial class Designer : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private Task _loadTask;

    private async void Designer_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try
        {
            _loadTask= Workbench.Instance.CurrentPackage.LoadObjects(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            await _loadTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _loadTask.Wait(); //Waits forever
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Where's my fault?

**Edit**
The Code Of `LoadObjects()`

```
public Task LoadObjects(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        LoadParameters(cancelToken);
        LoadConditionChecks(cancelToken);
        LoadConditonRules(cancelToken);
        LoadOperations(cancelToken);
    }, cancelToken);
}
```

I pass the Token the Sub-Methods since the loops are actually there...

Comment: Task cancellation requires the task that is running to check if it's been cancelled. It sounds like it doesn't do this, but I don't know what Workbench is.

Comment: Do you control the code for `Workbench.Instance.CurrentPackage.LoadObjects`. Are you certain it is respecting the cancellation token?

Comment: Somewhere in the code that accept the `CancellationToken` there should be a check for cancellation like `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested ` or `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ` If it is not there are just atb the very end you will get this behavior

Comment: I've added the Code of `LoadObjects()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hitting a deadlock on the UI thread by awaiting it and calling `Task.Wait()`. Avoid `Task.Wait` at all costs.

Service the result of the cancellation in an asynchronous continuation, like this:

```
private async void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    await _loadTask;
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    this.Close();
}
```

This is the only time `async void` is acceptable.

My favourite async code guy Stephen Cleary provides a brilliant blog post explaining why you should avoid `Task.Wait` and `Task.Result` as blocking mechanisms - [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

---

For what its worth, when I do cancellation, I never wait for the task to finish. I respond immediately to the cancellation and let the task finish in the background. This provides a responsive UI experience for the user. If I need to get a result from a cancelled task I will put some UI work in to communicate 'waiting for end of operation' after the user clicks cancel.

Comment: This was it... In all the examples I've found with google they all did the `.Wait()`thing...

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the cancellation token. This pattern is known as cooperative task cancellation - both the consumer and the executing code need to service the cancellation activity. This helps you maintain correct state after cancellation.

The solution - update your LoadX() methods:

```
void LoadParameters(cancelToken)
{
    ... // do some work

    cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    ... // do some more work
}
```